# Hibernate encrpytion using column transformers read/write doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, encryption

I am using mysql 5.5 and hibernate 4.3.0.Final. I have tried to use the column transformers to encrypt and decrypt data on the fly. I have no errors at all when activating hibernate or using this .hbm. Here is what I have in the .hbm:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false"> <classname="com.someplace.someapp.dao.SomeHistory"                                          table="SOME_APP.SOME_HISTORY" lazy="false">
     <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="uuid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name">
        <column 
          name="NAME" not-null="true"
          read="decrypt(NAME)"
          write="encrypt(?)"/>
    </property>
    <property name="description">
        <column 
          name="VALUE" 
          read="decrypt(VALUE)"
          write="encrypt(?)"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I looked at the data in the tables and the data have not been encrypted. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) I think encrypt is there but no decrypt, try Aes_encrypt and decrypt. Do you have any business rule asking you to encrypt using regular encrypt function?

Comment: I did look at the 5.5 api and was using only the encrypt function for the transformer in the .hbm file (since I had also seen that one was available) and I did not use the decrypt function since I didn't see one with still no results. I can try using the aes_ functions to see if they work to encrypt but I would have thought the regular encrypt function would have worked this way. I don't have a business rule asking me to encrypt a certain way but I am tired of always depending on lots of third party tools and would like to use what's already available instead of adding another for encryption.